# Как работает эта конструкция?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, lambda

```
def function(message: types.Message):
```

Как работает `message: types.Message`?

Что это, анонимная функция без ключевого слова lambda?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Answer (score 5):

Это аннотация типа ([pep-3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)). Подсказка, что `message` будет с типом `types.Message`.

Такая аннотация, например, позволит IDE подсказывать поля `message`, а так же проверять, что в функцию объект был передан правильного типа.

Если тип переданного объекта не совпадает с указанным в аннотации, то ошибок при выполнении кода не будет